# how to create dynamic map with new markers appear every second?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, real-time

May I ask how to create real time map like thiswebsite: www.lightningmaps.org ? Every second there are some new markers jump out.

I want to create a real time map to track ip locations which are provided in my dynamic database.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript setInterval to whatever server side script you use to grab the DB content at a regular interval, then parse out the returned data to make your markers.